# How do I make a video play on an image?

Tags: special-effects, visual-effects

I am trying to make an intro for a video where the video only plays within an image. In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bz2wD4XZ3GM), during the first 5 seconds, an image appears as white over the video and then switches to the video playing within the image over black. How do I reproduce that effect?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for free program that allows PiP, and cutting/splicing](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/10891/looking-for-free-program-that-allows-pip-and-cutting-splicing)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the logo or title in Black and white then you will simply mix between them as they mix differently on the video background. But the trick is making sure that your editor can do "layer math".
Perhaps you've noticed in Photoshop or other paint programs that you can do more than simply Mix 2 images together (like a dissolve)?

You want to look for a Blend type for the logo/title clip, some apps call this Composite type.

1. For the image to appear white over video, you would use the white
   logo on a black background then mix by an "Add" function. Where the
   image is black there is nothing to add. Where it is white then it
   all gets added on top of the video.
2. For the image to appear black with video in the logo shape, you would use the white logo on a black background then mix by a "Multiply" function. Where the image is black the video gets multiplied down to 100 (or black). Where it is white then it all gets multiplied by zero (transparent).

Then apply a dissolve to then end of one logo blend clip into another logo blend clip.